# asp.net usercontrol dropdown selectedindex and selectedvalue empty

Tags: jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, user-controls, selectedindex

im coding a new usercontrol a dropdown my code is

```
        <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="StylishDDL.ascx.cs" Inherits="JDropDown.Controls_StylishDDL" %>   
     <script src="Jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Jquery/jquery.selectbox-0.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function () {
                        $('#ddlStytlish').selectbox();
                    });
        </script>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStytlish" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
        </asp:DropDownList>

namespace JDropDown
{
    public partial class Controls_StylishDDL : UserControl
    {
        public string _selectedvalue = "";
        public int _selectedIndex = 0;
        public Controls_StylishDDL( )
        {

        }
        public Controls_StylishDDL(int selectedIndex , string selectedval)
        {
            SelectedIndx = selectedIndex;
            SelectedVal = selectedval;
        }

        public string SelectedVal
        {
            get
            {
                _selectedvalue = this.ddlStytlish.SelectedValue;
                return _selectedvalue;
            }
            set { _selectedvalue = value; }
        }

        public int SelectedIndx
        {
            get
            {
                _selectedIndex = this.ddlStytlish.SelectedIndex;
                return this._selectedIndex;
            }

            set { this._selectedIndex = value; }
        }
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ddlStytlish.AutoPostBack = false;
            LoadStates();
        }
```

when i use this control it work fine except its seletected index is always  0 and selected value is always null how i maintain its index and value

Comment: or anyone can tell me how to inherit drowpdown to usercontrol or something like that

Answer (score -1):

For a user control there are two choices to persist state:

1. The user control properties are just wrappers around properties of the controls contained in it (which persist their state)
2. The user control persists its own state

In this case, the user control (it is more like a wrapper around another control) is reading some properties from a dropdownlist in the get {}, but it is not setting them back in the set {}. One option is this:

```
public string SelectedVal
{
    get
    {
        _selectedvalue = this.ddlStytlish.SelectedValue;
        return _selectedvalue;
    }
    set 
    { 
        _selectedvalue = value; 
        this.ddlStytlish.SelectedValue = value; 
    }
}
```

The other option is to persist the properties of the user control like it is explained in this video:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-persist-the-state-of-a-user-control-during-a-postback

Comment: im loading dropdown in usercontrol how can i get selectedindex and selectedvalue in my webpage
when i use your code it always get 0 selectedindex whatever i select